# Can't see my token in the wallet

Tags: contract-deployment

I'm new to ethereum and tried to create a basic token, I deployed contract according with instruction on ethereum website but for some reason it stuck on "deploying contract" phase.

My wallet is fully synced, and transaction is confirmed about a day ago but I don't see my token on contracts page in the wallet and can't access admin page - it still says "creating contract".

[image]

Etherscan sees my token, but my wallet does not: https://etherscan.io/token/0x7c8a25cecf3e1d782028cb0ae7f0e23d2a87410c

Would be grateful for any suggestions of what can be wrong and what can I do to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, that you need to add your token by clicking 'Watch token' at the bottom of "Contracts" menu.
[image: Watch token button]

After you'll click this button, you'll need to paste there address of your token. It is `0x7c8a25cecf3e1d782028cb0ae7f0e23d2a87410c`

Also, you need to click 'Watch Contract'

[image: Watch contract button]

Then paste there interface of your contract and address of your contract.

If you still can't see tokens, you can use wallet.ethereum.org with MetaMask extension for browser.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to add token, but when I click on "watch contract" it asks for something called 'json interface' - where should I get it? I followed instructions on ethereum.org/token - not a word about such thing. And I still unable to admin my token.

Comment: Could you show me your code?
Basically, you can use Remix to get JSON-Interface, but if you don't how, just send me your code, I'll compile it :)

Comment: I used remix to create json-interface and successfully added my token to Ethereum Wallet, I still can't admin it however and for some reason it shows balance in Ether instead of my token, I thought something may be wrong with my code and just copied token code from ethereum.org/token, deployed it and still got the same problems - no admin page and when I add it with "watch token" button it shows zero balance instead of 1 bil. tokens I created on start.

Comment: Would you like to try wallet.ethereum.org ?
It seems like bug in Ethereum Wallet

Comment: Nope, still not working: Unable to connect. Please start geth with the following options: geth --rpc --rpccorsdomain "https://wallet.ethereum.org"
I guess I give up on Ethereum for now and return when it will be properly developed, but thanks for your help :)

Comment: Also you can try MyEtherWallet to interact with your contract, it uses online Block-Explorer.